# Postgresql - Reformat Query return order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Recursive Query that returns a non linear tree, but it returns all of the rootnodes first. (where parent_id is null)

How would I order the rows in which my query gets one rootnode, gets the entire tree, followed by getting the second rootnode and then getting that entire tree...so on etc.

```
With RECURSIVE cte AS
(
   (
    SELECT * 
    FROM comments 
    WHERE thread_id = 1
      AND parent_id is NULL 
    ORDER BY upvoted DESC 
    FETCH FIRST 10 ROW ONLY
   )
   UNION
   SELECT t.*
   From comments t
     JOIN cte rt ON rt.comment_id = t.parent_id
 )
  SELECT cte.comment_id, cte.date_posted, cte.posted_by, cte.posted_by_user, cte.thread_id,
            cte.parent_id, cte.comments, cte.post_title, cte.posted_to_group, cte.upvoted, cte.downvoted,
            cte.depth, cv.user_id, cv.vote, cv.thread_id
     from cte LEFT JOIN
          commentsvoted cv
          ON cte.comment_id = cv.id
          AND cv.user_id = '82411580-6355-490e-be79- e7db9f561f66'
```

If I add:

```
ORDER BY coalesce(parent_id, comment_id), comment_id
```

to my last select, it returns what I have described **except** it ignores:

```
ORDER BY upvoted DESC
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions in the `order by`:

```
ORDER BY MAX(upvoted) OVER (PARTITION BY coalesce(parent_id, comment_id)) DESC, 
         coalesce(parent_id, comment_id),   -- keep this in the event of ties,
         (case when parent_id is null then 1 else 0 end),
         comment_id
```

Comment: This causes the parent_id's to get out of order

Comment: @davids. . . . I think your original code had the same problem, but you may not have seen it for your particular result set.  I added an additional condition which should put the parents first.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I just can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I think I'm going to filter out the rows in JSON instead